# Set multiple git remotes on a repo and set a default one

Tags: git, github

Have a git repo with lots of user forks. Would like to register all user forks on the main repo and set `origin` to be default. I am able to add multiple remote's AFTER I download the repo using `git config --local remote.user1.url git@github.user1/repo.git` but this is only local to my machine I believe.

Wondering if there's a way to register multiple forks in the `.git/config` file and push it up, so all registered forks are available to everyone who downloads the main repo. Any help is greatly appreciated ‍♂️

Comment: You should not be conscious of forks of your repo, and you have no ability to change anything about them. You certainly should not be adding them as remotes. The whole idea makes no sense. What is it you are trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Trying to get around an issues with Jenkins GitSCM plugin. The plugin doesn't recognize user remotes that were not in the workspace at the START of the job; even though I explicitly add user remote in the pre-scm script step. So thought if I somehow register user remotes with the main repo, the plugin will know about it and can pull. Wondering if you have any tips for this ‍♂️

Comment: The issue seems to be with your workflow rather than the plugin. If you could explain more about how the issue you described is affecting your workflow, it might easier to provide an alternative solution

Comment: Posted the details here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536533/jenkins-gitscm-plugin-not-recognizing-remotes-added-in-pre-scm-step. Thanks guys for your time!!